# How are custom classes auto-discovered and picked up?

Tags: 8, plugins

I've been trying to get [this sub module](https://www.drupal.org/project/selective_better_exposed_filters) working for the better part of 8 hours, but I cannot get any debug/log statements to fire inside the sub module.

Since its only 3 files, I copy pasted the code out into an enabled custom module, changed the namespace and tried to see if I could figure out what was going on. In short, this code extends:

`modules/contrib/better_exposed_filters/src/Plugin/better_exposed_filters/filter/DefaultWidget.php` with
`modules/contrib/selective_better_exposed_filters/src/Plugin/better_exposed_filters/filter/DefaultWidget.php`

and

`modules/contrib/better_exposed_filters/src/Plugin/better_exposed_filters/filter/RadioButtons.php` with
`modules/contrib/selective_better_exposed_filters/src/Plugin/better_exposed_filters/filter/RadioButtons.php`

However, despite heavily modifying both the these files in both `better_exposed_filters` and `selective_better_exposed_filters` I couldn't get any debug or log information to show.

Now, `better_exposed_filters` `DefaultWidget.php` file extends another file called `FilterWidgetBase.php`. **If I modify THIS file I can change what appears in the form**. However, if I copy/paste this exact file into an equivalently named file in my custom module and change the namespace, nothing happens.

It 'feels' like Drupal simply isn't discovering these custom classes that extend the `better_exposed_filters` core classes. Without error output I cannot know for sure, does anyone know if this is the issue? Any best practices for debugging this sort of thing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107292/discussion-on-question-by-plambre-how-are-custom-classes-auto-discovered-and-pic).